# can i have wifi repeater of a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I need ethernet connection in a room which is too far from main modem. And wifi signal is pretty weak there.

So I am thinking of making a relay network. My question is is it possible?

Bottom line is - I want repeater with ethernet port in that room and something in between it and the main modem.

I have at least 4 different old wifi modems/routers and a repeater cost 8 quid. Can I make it work?

Comment: Yes; Every time you extend it though you will reduce the bandwidth.  Since you already extended it once the effect would be doubled

Comment: I will not.  My comment just mentions a common fact about Network Extenders which isn't worth submitting an answer which will just be low hanging fruit for serial down voters

Comment: fair enough.. but can you add some proof of what you said, I will add it to my answer for future generations :) its not a common fact at all. if you connect 2 routers with a cable it is somewhat obvious they can communicate but whats going on in an extender brain - who knows

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get your question clearly, but if you want to extend your wifi signal just buy yourself the cheapest simple wifi router (or re-use some old one) and make it part of your network! To configure it you need to use some pc/laptop not connected to your network and connect this router to it to set-it up. Go to it's web interface and set the same ssid, wifi security and password as your primary router has. Set the channels on routers different and distant from each other. Then give it a fixed ip and disable DHCP. Note that after you disable DHCP you will not be able to connect to it's web interface most likely. So in this case you need to set a static ip such as 192.168.0.2 (the same subnet as is the static ip of the new router) on your computer's network card and then it should work again. When you are done setting it up, just connect it to your LAN somewhere where you have a weak wifi signal and all wifi devices should automatically switch to this new access point when near it.
For detailed guide check [this article on PCAdvisor](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-use-router-as-repeater-3633135/)

Comment: thanks for taking time to give much info.. however its not what I asked. I want to know if I can extend an extender. **not** extender -> hub -> extender, but hub -> extender -> extender..

Comment: what kind of extender do you use exactly? Because in my scenario the second wifi AP works basically as an extender and IMHO there can be any number of these connected to LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Using the info from the comment above: "Yes; Every time you extend it though you will reduce the bandwidth. Since you already extended it once the effect would be doubled"